# How to specialize a template for const and non const containers?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constants, variadic-templates

I'm trying to make 2 specialization of a template :

- One which accept a non const containers
- Another one which accept const containers

**My current code is :**

```
template<class T>
struct A{
    constexpr static int value=0;
};

template<template<typename>class T,typename...Args>
struct A<T<Args...>>{//accept non const containers
    constexpr static int value=1;
};

template<template<typename>class T,typename...Args>
struct A<T<Args...> const>{//accept const containers
    constexpr static int value=2;
};
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/ZPl1WX)

But that code does not work, if I use const container, it use the first `A`'s instantiation instead of the third one .

```
using Type=const std::array<int,10>;
std::cout<<A<Type>::value;//output is 0
```

I tried removing

```
template<class T>
struct A{
    constexpr static int value=0;
};
```

But it give many [errors](https://ideone.com/5odSDV) ..

What should I do ?

Comment: The code your showing us compiles fine, can you be more specific about the error?

Comment: @awesomeyi yes it compiles fine but the result that I want is 2 not 0

Comment: I did not check, but probably you forgot about ellipsis in your template parameter: `template<typename...>class T` not `template<typename>class T`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want the template template parameter to have variadic template argument list (all standard containers in fact have more than one template parameter):

```
template< template<typename...> class T, typename...Args >
//                         ^^^
```

Then this code

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct A{
    constexpr static int value=0;
};

template<template<typename...>class T,typename...Args>
struct A<T<Args...>>{//accept non const containers
    constexpr static int value=1;
};

template<template<typename...>class T,typename...Args>
struct A<T<Args...> const>{//accept const containers
    constexpr static int value=2;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << A<const std::vector<int>>::value;
}
```

outputs `2` as you expect.

But it still won't work with `std::array`, because it includes a non-type template parameter in its parameter list (and that can't match a variadic pack of types). This can't be solved in a generic way, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 6):

I think you can do this without the variadic template parameters:

```
template<class T>
struct A{
    constexpr static int value=0;
};

template<class T>
struct A<T const> {
    constexpr static int value=2;
};


int main()
{
    std::cout << A<const std::vector<int>>::value;
}
```

Comment: yes with your code it accepts somthing like const int too ,which I don't want to .

Comment: +1. With some SFINAE or static assert, it can be made to disallow `T`s that are not class types (see `type_traits` header).

Comment: +1 I think this is the most practical approach (although jrok's answer explains more clearly what's wrong with the original code).

Answer (score 2):

Always use type_traits.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   std::cout << std::is_const< const std::vector<int> > ::value << '\n';
   std::cout << std::is_const< std::vector<int> >::value << '\n';

   std::cout << std::is_const< const std::array<int, 4> >::value << '\n';
   std::cout << std::is_const< std::array<int, 4> > ::value << '\n';
}
```

output is as expected:

```
1
0
1
0
```